# Dld of an xml-file failed using Windows wininet.dll function

Tags: xml, download, wininet

for more than two years it was perfectly working. I dld. every Sunday a csv.file. But now csv isn't available any more (404 error).
But there is an xml-file which I would like to download it the same way
 with the same wininet-functions - just with another url.
The previous csv-url looked like:

```
  http://calendar.forex-tsd.com/calendar.php?csv=1&date=20150927&calendar[]=4&gmt=0
```

Now it should (must) be:

```
  string strUrl = "http://www.forexfactory.com/ffcal_week_this.xml";
  string moz = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; Q312461)";
  int HttpOpen=InternetOpenW( moz, 0,"0","0",0);
  // NO Error, handle is: 2214592768
  uint x =   INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE 
           | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
           | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;

  int HttpRequest = InternetOpenUrlW(HttpOpen,strUrl,"0", 0, x, 0 ); 
  err = getWinErrors(); // Error: 12150 
                        // ERROR_WINHTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND:
                        // The requested header cannot be located.
```

Hmm?
In InternetOpenUrlW(..) 'my' header = "0", its length is set to 0
And the xml-file just looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
  <weeklyevents>
     <event>
        <title>Daylight Saving Time Shift</title>
        <country>NZD</country>
        <date><![CDATA[09-26-2015]]></date>
        <time><![CDATA[2:00pm]]></time>
        <impact><![CDATA[Holiday]]></impact>
        <forecast />
        <previous />
     </event>
     <event>
  ...
     </event>
     <event>
        <title>Daylight Saving Time Shift</title>
        <country>AUD</country>
        <date><![CDATA[10-03-2015]]></date>
        <time><![CDATA[4:00pm]]></time>
        <impact><![CDATA[Holiday]]></impact>
        <forecast />
        <previous />
     </event>
  </weeklyevents>
```

The header has to be how?
Thanks in advance!
Gooly

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! 
The Metatrader - 4 before it's last update to build 890 - wasn't able to 'understand' NULL! We had to use "0". But now **this** causes the error as it now accepts and understands NULL (no error) and it fails using "0".

```
  InternetOpenUrlW(HttpOpen,strUrl, NULL, 0, x, 0 ); // working
```

Sigh.
Anyway thanks!